Unexpected end of file encountered
still new to this and still learning
still lack of knowledge using gui turbo assembler
can someone help me with this problem? thanks
.MODEL SMALL 
.stack 100h

sys_exit equ 1
sys_read equ 3
sys_write equ 4
stdin equ 0
stdout equ 1

.data
.code
start:
    msg1 db "enter a number: ", len1 equ $- msg1
    
    msg2 db "enter a number: ",  len2 equ $- msg2
    
    msg3 db "the sum is ", len3 equ $- msg3
    
        num1 resb 2
        num2 resb 2
        res resb 1
    
.bss
        
        
        
        section .text
        global_start
        
        
        
        mov eax,sys_write
        mov ebx,stdout
        mov ecx,msg1
        mov edx,len1
        int 21h
        
        mov eax,sys_read
        mov ebx,stdin
        mov ecx,num1
        mov edx,2
        int 21h
        
        mov eax,sys_write
        mov ebx stdout
        mov ecx,msg2
        mov edx,len2
        int 21h
       
        mov eax,sys_read
        mov ebx,stdin
        mov ecx,num2
        mov edx,2
        int 21h
        
        mov eax,sys_write
        moc ebx,stdout
        mov ecx,msg3
        mov edx,len3
        int 21h
        
        mov eax,[num1]
        sub eax,'0'
        
        mov ebx, [num2]
        sub ebx,'0'
        
        add eax,ebx
        add eax,'0'
        
        mov [res],eax
        
        mov eax,sys_write
        mov ebx,stdout
        mov ecx,res
        mov edx,1
        int 21h
        
        exit:
        
        mov eax,sys_exit
        xor ebx,ebx
        int 21h
        
        


What operating system is this supposed to target? I don't know any that use int 21h with sys_exit equ 1

You tried to use linux syscalls via DOS int 21h. That will not work. Also you used sections and variables wrong. Anyway, your immediate error is you are missing an end directive.
